# How to match asset price data from a csv file to another csv file with relevant news by date

Tags: python, csv, sentiment-analysis, finance

I am researching the impact of news article sentiment related to a financial instrument and its potenatial effect on its instruments's price. I have tried to get the timestamp of each news item, truncate it to minute data (ie remove second and microsecond components) and get the base shareprice of an instrument at that time, and at several itervals after that time, in our case t+2. However, program created twoM to the file, but does not return any calculated price changes

Previously, I used Reuters Eikon and its functions to conduct the research, described in the article below.

https://developers.refinitiv.com/article/introduction-news-sentiment-analysis-eikon-data-apis-python-example

However, instead of using data available from Eikon, I would like to use my own csv news file with my own price data from another csv file. I am trying to match the

```py
excel_file = 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\PycharmProjects\\JRA\\sentimenteikonexcel.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
sentiment = df.Sentiment
print(sentiment)


start = df['GMT'].min().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
end = df['GMT'].max().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

spot_data = 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\Desktop\\stocksss.csv'
spot_price_10 = pd.read_csv(spot_data)
print(spot_price_10)

df['twoM'] = np.nan


for idx, newsDate in enumerate(df['GMT'].values):
    sTime = df['GMT'][idx]
    sTime = sTime.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    try:
        t0 = spot_price_10.iloc[spot_price_10.index.get_loc(sTime),2]
        df['twoM'][idx] = ((spot_price_10.iloc[spot_price_10.index.get_loc((sTime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))),3]/(t0)-1)*100)
    except:
        pass
print(df)
```

However, the programm is not able to return the twoM price change values

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you got a warning because you are trying to make changes on views. As soon as you have 2 `[]` (one for the column, one for the row) you can only read. You must use  `loc` or `iloc` to write a value:

```
...
try:
    t0 = spot_price_10.iloc[spot_price_10.index.get_loc(sTime),2]
    df.loc[idx,'twoM'] = ((spot_price_10.iloc[spot_price_10.index.get_loc((sTime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))),3]/(t0)-1)*100)
except:
    pass
...
```